# bootstrap 4 - arrange images in particular?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a simple page in my Laravel and in that page, I have three sections which is mainly `navigation`, `content` and `footer`. I got the navigation and footer layout completed. In the content section, I wish to use bootstrap to place my images layout like this:

Image:

[image]

This is just a general idea but I need it to be responsive so it fits the mobile layout as well.

What I have tried is to use `Masonry` for CSS but it does not fit the mobile layout responsively. I tried using bootstrap 4 but the alignment between IMG3 and IMG4/5 are too far apart and placing margin does not align them near enough.

My code:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" class="img-fluid custom-position-1" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm col-8">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-fluid custom-position-2" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm custom-position-3">
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Kitchen.jpg')}}" class="img-fluid custom-position-3" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col col-8">
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Shop_Page.jpg')}}" class=" img-fluid custom-position-4" alt="">
      </div>    
      <div class="col">
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Sofa.jpg')}}"  class="img-fluid custom-position-5" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection

.row {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}




.custom-position-1{
 position: relative;
 bottom: -160px;
 left: 50px;
 height:100px;
 object-fit: cover;
}


.custom-position-2{
 position:relative;
 right:100px;
 object-fit:cover;
}


.custom-position-3{
 position: relative;
 bottom: -160px;
 left: 50px;
 height:100px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.custom-position-4{
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 width:800px;
 object-fit: cover;
}




.custom-position-5{

    position: relative;
    height:300px;
 left:50px;
 top: 100px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make it good?

Comment: Please post relevant code where the problem is occurred. Please post the work till you have done.

Comment: Please post your requirement image layout. The current layout provided is not able to understand completely.

Comment: @Nitheesh I have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a solution like this?

If you want to have some spacing use margin classes.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
[class*="col-"],
.flex-grow-0 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img-fluid {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-8 p-0">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  p-0 d-flex">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="flex-grow-0 mt-auto">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grow-0">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost like that, but in the top right image, it should be "push" lower. Also there should be small spaces/gap between each of the images.

Comment: And the images clashes with my navigation bar though, why is that?

Comment: Check mu updated answer? still that causing the issue?

Comment: @LordJesus Please check my answer and approve if the requirement is satisfied.

Comment: Yes that is the solution I want. Is there a way to adjust the image height and width of each image? I want to lower the height and increase the width.

Comment: Because one of my image for best seller has a different pixels so it's more vertical and pushes the picture down.

Comment: @LordJesus can you post your requirement image?

Comment: @LordJesus You can use images of any resolution. The images will be fit in the width in the right portion. You can check my updated solution. The images used are of different dimensions.

Comment: @LordJesus I have provided the core part of your issue. You can work out yourself and fit that to your requirement. If your requirement is satisfied please approve my answer.